# How Can I Add Conditional CSS Classes in Magento Go?

Tags: html, css, magento

How can I add conditional CSS classes to the HTML or BODY element in Magento Go? I would like to add this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

to my site.

Comment: Don't any of their GO Cpanel editors in your GO account let you do any of this? There are limits on what can be done with GO, please don't confuse it with Community Edition.

Comment: No @FiascoLabs I haven't found where I can change this in any of their editors or anywhere in the account, which is why I'm asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features of Magento GO is it's limitations on what can be changed in order to prevent website downtime due to inexperienced people making code edits that they cannot back out of. All the design is exposed in the Magento GO Theme, Layout and Design editor suite.

If it is not available in the [Magento GO toolset,](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/category/name/themes-and-design/) then it is not available as a conscious desire on their part to limit the changes that can be made in the Magento GO hosted environment.

See this question in Magento.Stackexchange [for more information on Magento Go limitations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/542/what-are-the-theming-limitations-of-magento-go)

Basically, you don't have access to directly edit the templates and layouts files. The `<html>` opening tag is found in the `templates/page` folder in 1col, 2col, 3col template files for Magento CE.